# "..of human immunoglobulin G" or "... of the human immunoglobulin G" - is definite article necessary?

Tags: articles

> The drug is comprised of light and heavy chains of **the** human immunoglobulin G.

Is **the** necessary here? Maybe the letter "G" works like the number in the phrase "He went to room 234", and thus no article is needed?

On the other hand, there's the word "human" that works like an adjective, and thus the definite article may still be necessary. It's complicated for me.

Comment: I think the definitive is optional here. Let's wait for expert comments.

Comment: No article. Nada! Niente! Nikto! Chemicals are uncountable.

Comment: @Mick - but it has that "human" adjective. An adjective often drives me to place an article..

Comment: Plenty of uncountably human stuff [here](http://www.onelook.com/?w=human+*&ls=a).

Comment: @Mick - "the extracellular domain of **the** human epidermal growth factor receptor 2" -- the definite article is wrong here too, since a receptor is a chemical (a large protein)?

Comment: If it is the name of a chemical ([and it is](https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/cancer-terms?cdrid=44570)), then "yes", no article. Note that you can say "**the** blah blah blah **protein**" (*protein* is countable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chemical names are always considered to be uncountable nouns, and do not take an article. It doesn't matter whether they are elements, such as [*hydrogen*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hydrogen), or complex biochemical molecules, such as [*human epidermal growth factor receptor 2*](https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/cancer-terms?cdrid=44570) (a protein).

Since [*protein*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/protein) can be countable, we can talk about "**the** human epidermal growth factor receptor 2 protein."

Answer (score 1):

It could go either way.

The definite article can be used to emphasize the adjective, for example to make clear that one is differentiating:

... the bovine immunoglobulin X...
... the feline immunoglobulin X...

The article isn't wrong but it isn't necessary.